# Both React components render with 2nd component's Prop values

Tags: reactjs, components, react-redux

I'm rather new to React, but fortunately I've been able to work past most of my issues thus far just going thru the docs. I'm currently stuck and could use some help.

The goal is to call this global function `loadFeaturedPlaylist()` using prop values from the `Tracklist` component as arguments, but what ends up happening is both `Tracklist` components are rendered with the same prop values.

Here is how I have the Tracklist Component set up:

```
export class Tracklist extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
       loadFeaturedPlaylist: React.PropTypes.func,
       playList: React.PropTypes.number,
       trackList: React.PropTypes.string
    }

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.props.loadFeaturedPlaylist(this.props.trackList, this.props.playList);
    }

    render() { 
        return(...);
    }
}
```

Here is the page I plan to render 2 different playlists:

```
export class ListenPage extends React.Component {  

 render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <section>
          <Tracklist trackList={'featured'} playList={64347989} />
        </section>

        <section>
          <Tracklist trackList={'ambient'} playList={49422646} />
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried `componentWillReceiveProps()` as a solution but got nowhere. So my question, is this a deeper issue with the `loadFeaturedPlaylist()` function and core API code, or is there a React.Component solution ?

EDIT: here is the function for reference:

```
  loadFeaturedPlaylist: (tracklist, playlist) => ({
    type: playlistActions.LOAD_FEATURED_TRACKS,
    payload: {
      tracklistId: tracklist,
      playlistId: playlist
    }
  })
```

Comment: where you sending this function as a prop to this component, and where you define it?

Answer (score 0):

I must say this is an excellent question.
There is at least one syntax item:

```
constructor(props){
// missing } ----->
```

The main problem is you made your prop types static.

```
static propTypes = {
       loadFeaturedPlaylist: React.PropTypes.func,
       playList: React.PropTypes.number,
       trackList: React.PropTypes.string
    }
```

And this is why they are shared among all instances:

```
<section>
    <Tracklist trackList={'featured'} playList={64347989} />
</section>

<section>
    <Tracklist trackList={'ambient'} playList={49422646} />
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also pretty new here. I have the same question Doron Brikman does, but assuming the function is coming into the component correctly... what if you gave `<Tracklist>` a `componentDidMount()` lifecycle hook and put your function there, instead of in the constructor?

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.loadFeaturedPlaylist(this.props.trackList, this.props.playList);
}
```

Comment: So this calls the function into the component correctly like my current method, but the main issue is still there with the duplicated playlist.